# getview() is not calling on button click?

Tags: java, android, listview, audio-player, android-music-player

I am developing a Music Player. All songs are placed in the `ListView` with a `ImageButton`. This button is playing and pause the songs. So I am using `getview()`. But when I am clicking on the `ImageButton`, the songs are playing and pausing, but the image of play/pause is not changing. My main issue as I think, is that, when I am clicking on the `ImageButton` it is not calling the `getview()`. So please help me.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtones);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtones);
    mAdapter = new RingtonesMusicAdapter(this, R.layout.ringtones_row);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 }

 public void invalidatePlayButtons(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mTrackData.size(); i++) {
        if (i != position) {
            try {
                //mTrackData.get(i).getRowItem().mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                if (MusicManager.getInstance().isPlaying(mTrackData.get(i))) {
                    MusicManager.getInstance().stop();
                    mTrackData.get(i).getRowItem().mProgressBar
                            .setProgress(0);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else
            mTrackData.get(i).getRowItem().mPlayButton
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    }
}

 public void onPlayClick(View view) {
    Object obj = view.getTag();

    if (obj != null && obj.getClass() == RowItem.class) {
        final RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) obj;
        if(rowItem.mPosition != mChantIndex ){
            if (!MusicManager.getInstance().isPlaying(rowItem)) {
                invalidatePlayButtons(rowItem.mPosition);
                MusicManager.getInstance().showProgressAnimation(rowItem.mProgressBar);
            //  rowItem.mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                if(rowItem.isPause){
                    //rowItem.mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    MusicManager.getInstance().setLengthTrack();
                }else{
                    rowItem.mMusicListener = this;
                    MusicManager.getInstance().playDownloadedTrack(rowItem);
                     if(rowItem.mPosition == mProgressbarIndex) {
                            mProgressbarIndex = -1;  
                        }
                        else {
                            mProgressbarIndex = rowItem.mPosition;
                        } 
                }
            }else if(MusicManager.getInstance().isPlaying(rowItem)){
                MusicManager.getInstance().pauseTrack(rowItem);
                MusicManager.getInstance().getLengthTrack();
                //rowItem.mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                rowItem.isPause = true;
            }
        }
    }else {
        invalidatePlayButtons(-1);
    }
    //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void onRefreshData(Refreshable refreshable, int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == SoundCloudManager.BITMAP_DATA) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


class RingtonesMusicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>{

    Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    public RingtonesMusicAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        mContext =context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTrackData.size();
    }

    public LinearLayout getItem(int position) {
        return null;
        }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout row;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row =(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        RowItem rowItem = new RowItem(position);
        mTrackData.get(position).setRowItem(rowItem);
        rowItem.mTrack = mTrackData.get(position);
        rowItem.setupRowForRingtone(row);
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Method `rowItem.setupRowForRingtone(row)` has the code for changing the play/pause the image.

Comment: is this an activity? or a fragment ? You have not called setContentView and you app throws no errors when you set an adapter to a listview ?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtones);
Sorry I forget to write this thing. I used it .

Comment: you have the button in the layout used to inflate the listview?? Then you will have to use an anonymous click listener, payClick method might not work. OnClick listener inside the adapter class, inside the getView method

Comment: It is working on another page, and there I am able to call the getview() on Button click. Please help me.

Comment: could you try setting every other element to focusable false ?? and focusable in touch mode to false also ? in the xml?

Comment: No I am not trying like this anything.

Comment: instead of returning null in getItem return the layout

Comment: Will you tell me how can i return the layout, becuase it is causing error ??

Comment: return mTrackData.get(position)